# EntityFramework Update Item by another Item

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this Code:

```
public static void SaveItem(Item itemFrom)
{
    using (myEntitites ctx = new myEntitites())
    {
        Item itemTo = ctx.Items.First(x => x.ID = itemFrom.ID);
        itemTo.Property1 = itemFrom.Property1;
        itemTo.Property2 = itemFrom.Property2;
        itemTo.Property3 = itemFrom.Property3;
        //..lot of properties 
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I'm wondering whether there is a way to update an item without assigning each property.

`itemFrom` is an updated version of `itemTo`.

Comment: itemTo = itemFrom should work

Comment: @King no, reassigning a variable doesn't update the tracked entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually attach the item to the context without getting an object from the database.
Entity Framework will update the correct row by using the primary key defined in the model.

```
public static void SaveItem(Item itemFrom)
{
    using (myEntitites ctx = new myEntitites())
    {
        ctx.Items.Attach(itemFrom);
        ctx.Entry(itemFrom).State = EntityState.Modified;
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I have to care about references if I use `Attach`? How does `Attach` know which Item to overwrite? By it's ID?

Comment: Yes, the attach method will use the primary key to find out what object to overwrite.